# New object structure prevents .serialize() success

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I have the following Node route:

```
function getBasePromise(base) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const users = await BaseUser.countDocuments({ baseId: base._id });
    resolve({
      base,
      users,
    });
  });  
}

async function fetcher() {
    try {
        const bases = await Base.find({ creatorId: req.params.id });
        const baseUserPromises = bases.map(base => getBasePromise(base));
        return await Promise.all(baseUserPromises);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
    }
}
```

I just was able to make this work, before I only had the `Base.find`. With only the Base model, I was able to serialize the object, and was hence able to use the id of each item in the front-end (React). 
After the above code, I now have an object formed like this:

```
{
    base: {base.find results},
    users: XX,
    messages: XX
}
```

With the new object structure serializing obviously does not work. How to fix this ?

**EDIT:**
If i don't serialize the above, I get the following:

```
0:
  base:
   {
     created: "2018-09-03T14:04:56.467Z", _id: "5b8d3fb3ccdfcc2e20540603", 
     creatorId: "004969bf0", title: "baseTest1"
   }
   messages: 2,
   users: 3
```

If I serialize via `bases.map(base => getBasePromise(base.serialize()))` I get the same base serialized, but 0s for `messages` and `users`:

```
0:
  base:
    {
      id: "5b8d3fb3ccdfcc2e20540603", creatorId: "5b86f7970cd98b2004969bf0", 
      title: "baseTest1", created: "2018-09-03T14:04:56.467Z"
    },
    messages: 0,
    users: 0
```

This is likely because my Schema model does not include a structure like the code in this edit, but only the base itself.

Comment: can you show us the serialization output before and now?

Comment: @Sid edited for clarification

Comment: Just to be sure, can you debug and check if actually the numbers of users is greater than 0?